# How to change the id of a unordered list of object type in jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new here and I'd like to ask a question about jQuery.

I have the unordered list like:

```
<ul id="pages">
  <li id="number1">
    <a href="#">contains sub table a</a>
  </li>
  <li id="number2">
    <a href="#">contains sub table b</a>
  </li>
  <li id="number3">
    <a href="#">contains sub table c</a>
  </li>
  <li id="number4">
    <a href="#">contains sub table d</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I'd like to add a different ID (new id will be same out of these id but it will be shuffle as per my requirements) to every li displayed in this `<ul>` (eg
    `<li id="number3"><a href="#">contains sub table d</a></li>` 
   ...)

Is there a way how to achieve this via jQuery?

I tried it using a for loop and this object but when i try to shuffle. Its duplicating the sub tables becouse of jQuery has child/nextsybling data inside this every object.

Comment: Hi mohit gupta, please include your code in the question.

Comment: Dynamic IDs are *quite* a code smell - please consider a different option to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Please try to mark your code by 4 spaced of indentation. Otherwise its hard to read, and especially HTML will not be shown at all but assumed to be part of your formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you should get all ids, shuffle them and reassign back to DOM elements:

```
const $items = $('#pages li');
const ids = $items.map((i, { id }) => id);

const shuffledIds = shuffle(ids); // This is your shuffle function

$items.each((i, e) => {
  e.id = shuffledIds[i];
});
```